# (VBS) how to taskkill a process when a specific window appear?

Tags: process, vbscript

In my VBScript, I need to `taskkill` process `example.exe` when `SPECIFICWINDOW` appears *(the window's name is different than the process name)* and need this command ready when `SPECIFICWINDOW` appears.

How can I do this, as I've ended the `.vbs` with:

```vb
Dim oShell

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

oShell.Run "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq the example.exe""", , True
```

---

My actual script is like that:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\example test.exe" 
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Const TimeToAllowActivationToComplete = 10000 ' 
Wscript.Sleep TimeToAllowActivationToComplete

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq example test""", , True
```

I set `TimetoAllowActivationToComplete` cause I can't taskill example test.exe after the specific window ( "End of the Operation") is coming.

Comment: Is `SPECIFICWINDOW` created by `example.exe`?

Comment: yes it's but, it has a different name than example.exe

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look tonight when I'm back at my PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AppActivate` in a loop to check for that specific window. Once found, then use `TaskKill` to kill the exe:

```
Set oWSH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do Until WindowFound
  WindowFound = oWSH.AppActivate("End of the Operation")
  WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
oWSH.Run "TaskKill /f /im example.exe",0,True
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1125391)

Comment: @Toto Yup, I was on mobile and accidentally selected `Answer` instead of `Comment`. It's all corrected now with comments and answers in their correct place.

Comment: Thanks, but it's doesn't work...

SpecificWindow is not an .exe, it's just a window at the end of the process that means it's ok, and for the last lign :

oWSH.Run "TaskKill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq " & WindowTitle & "*""",0,True

WindowTitle is the exe i want to taskill just after the SpecificWindows appears

Comment: The code worked fine for my test using an mspaint window. If you can provide details about the specific exe and window title you are trying to monitor/kill, I can provide a more targeted answer. What specifically is not working? Is the AppActivate not detecting the window you specified? If so, check case and maybe specify more or less text (it will match on a partial window title). The TaskKill command should work fine specifying either the window title or the exe name, since you said the window is created by the same exe.

Comment: when the exe end his process ( example.exe), a window is generated, but this windows hasn't an explicite name, i used AutoIT to see the name of this windows , and it said " End of the Operation".

Comment: my vbscript send example.exe, and 3 "enter" to validate the process ( example.exe is a backup program). Next, the save goes on, and when it's finished, this windows, named " End of the Operation" ( that's what autoiT said..) is coming. So , it's at this moment that i want to kill example.exe, just after the window "End of the Operation" comes . it's Ok for you? hard to explain, my english is bad ^^thanks for all your answers

Comment: What is the name of the backup software? If I can download and install the same software, and recreate the issue, then I can work on a VBScript or AutoIt solution for you.

Comment: In the meantime, I've edited my answer to something that *should* work. Just change "example.exe" to the actual exe name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using the `WINDOWTITLE` filter you need to provide the **title of the window** ("End of Operation") not the name of the executable. Also, if the name of the window changes or adds extra information, the `eq` might fail as a partial match is not equal. I think you can use `*` for a partial match (`cat*` matches "cat", "catch"; `*cat*` matches "cat", "a cat", "zcatapult")

If you want to kill the specific executable by name, then you need to use the `IMAGENAME` filter instead.

[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)